# How can i improve test coverage?

Tags: unit-test, class

I am new for test class but I have covered 54%.My class having web service i don't know how to write test class to  web service. Please can any one help me out.I need to move production..

Apex class:

```
global class Searchaddress {

public String accName{get;set;}
public String StNumber{get;set;}
public String Bcity{get;set;}
public String BPostalcode{get;set;}
public String BCountry{get;set;}
public String Snumber{get;set;}
public String street{get;set;}
public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}

public Id accId{get;set;}
string Id;
list<Account>updateAdd=new list<Account>();

public Searchaddress(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

 id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
   refreshPage=false;
 }

public void autosave(){

 if(StNumber!=''|| Bcity!=''|| BPostalcode!= ''|| BCountry!=''){
    for(Account updatelist:[SELECT id,Rfleet_Main_Address_Number__c,Rfleet_Main_address_Street__c,BillingAddress,BillingCity,BillingCountry,BillingLatitude,BillingLongitude,BillingPostalCode,BillingState,BillingStreet FROM Account where id=:id]){
        updatelist.BillingStreet=StNumber;
        updatelist.BillingCity=Bcity;
        updatelist.BillingPostalCode=BPostalcode;
        updatelist.BillingState='';
        updatelist.BillingCountry=BCountry;
        updatelist.Rfleet_Main_Address_Number__c=Snumber;
        updatelist.Rfleet_Main_address_Street__c=street;

        updateAdd.add(updatelist);
      }

    update updateAdd;
   refreshPage=true; 
    //PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + id);//ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')+'?inline=0');
   // return pageRef;
 }
 //return null;
    }


public class Properties 
    {
        public String city;
        public String label;
        public String id;
        public String postcode;
        public String name;
        public String citycode;
        public String context;
        public Double score;
        public String type;

    }

 @RemoteAction
 global static list<String> restapi(string accName){
        string jsonStr;  

        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/JSON');
        req.setEndpoint('http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(accName,'UTF-8'));//+'&'+'limit'+'='+'10');// 
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        List<String> calOut = new List<String>();
        jsonStr= res.getBody();
        system.debug('res1===>'+res.getBody());
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);

        List<String> calOut1 = new List<String>();

          JSON2Apex parsed = JSON2Apex.parse(res.getBody());
          for (JSON2Apex.Features f : parsed.Features) 
          {
              JSON2Apex.Properties p = f.Properties ;

               // calOut1.add(p.label+ ', ' + p.context+ ',' + p.city+ ', ' + p.postcode);
              calOut1.add(p.label+' '+'FRANCE');


          }
          return calOut1;
    }
 }
```

My test class:

```
@isTest
public class Searchaddress_test {
    static testMethod void Testsearchaddress() {

        Account test = new Account(Name='chinna',Montant__c=5);
        insert test;
        test.BillingStreet='chengalpattu';

        update test;
        Account myTestTrainee = [SELECT id From Account LIMIT 1];
        PageReference myVfPage = Page.RFLEET_Searchaddress;
        system.test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', myTestTrainee.id);//Pass Id to page
        ApexPAges.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myTestTrainee);
        Searchaddress apextestclass=new Searchaddress(sc);
        apextestclass.autosave();
        account test1 = new account(BillingStreet = 'chengalpttu');
        insert test1;
        //String test1 = 'chengalpattu';
//Searchaddress.autosave(test1);

         }

}
```

This part i need to cover
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To prevent tests from being skipped and to increase code coverage, Apex provides the built-in `WebServiceMock interface` and the `Test.setMock` method that you can use to receive fake responses in a test method.

When you create an Apex class from a WSDL, the methods in the auto-generated class call `WebServiceCallout.invoke`, which performs the callout to the external service. When testing these methods, you can instruct the Apex runtime to generate a fake response whenever `WebServiceCallout.invoke` is called.

To do so, implement the `WebServiceMock interface` and specify a fake response that the Apex runtime should send.

```
global class YourWebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {

        // Create response element from the autogenerated class.
        // Populate response element.
        // Add response element to the response parameter, as follows:
        response.put('response_x', responseElement); 
   }
}
```

more information can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your response Tushar Sharma. Can i need to create new class for WebServiceMock? Can you please elaborate what do i need to create in my test class?

Comment: yes you need to create new mock class and in your test class set this mock class as::  Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

Comment: hi Tushar SharmaI, got a error like this:Variable does not exist: responseElement .      please help me

Comment: @kirank you need to replace this response with the actual respone what you are expecting in your callout  docSample.EchoStringResponse_element respElement = 
           new docSample.EchoStringResponse_element();
       respElement.EchoStringResult = 'Mock response';
       response.put('response_x', respElement);

Comment: I  got error like this :Variable does not exist: responseElement. How can i  resolve this error...

Comment: ,how to test the rest api in test class step by step execution?please help me.

Comment: @kirank you need to study aboutMockcallout else a simple solution is use Test.isRunningTest(). You need to add this method in your main class .read in detail [here](http://michaelwelburn.com/2014/03/03/a-better-way-to-use-test-isrunningtest-in-apex/)

Answer (score 0):

When We call web service  in apex code , Then for test class of the same apex code We have to set Mock response before call the method in which web service is exist . For Mock response We have to create Mock Response class Which implements mock interface